# Is it possible to type in macron (e.g. "ā") without using U.S. Extended Keyboard?

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut

I want to type in macron (e.g. <kbd>ā</kbd>) in my OS X, but after I searched for how to type in it, I got that I first must use U.S. Extended Keyboard as suggested [in this article](http://www.personal.psu.edu/ejp10/psu/gotunicode/macron.html#mac).

However, once I switch to U.S. Extended Keyboard, I cannot type in <kbd>å</kbd> any more with <kbd>⇧+a</kbd> and <kbd>a</kbd>, because on U.S. Extended Keyboard, it provides you with the aforementioned macron letter.

So is it possible to type in macron with normal English keyboard on OS X?

Comment: Are you currently using Yosemite, or which OS?

Comment: @bjbk Yosemite, but I'm able to switch to El Capitan immediately if it's possible there.

Comment: Possibility "Alt+Maj+," to create "¯", and add in Shortcut "¯a" to create the "ā" (and so on for each letter). Possibly, any shortcut could be fine, but this one seems legit since it create a kind of macron.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keep US Extended and use it to type your <kbd>å</kbd>. It's <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd> and then <kbd>a</kbd>.

Comment: The OP wanted to know if there's a way to *avoid* using the U.S. Extended keyboard.

Comment: Does U.S. Extended Keyboard exist anymore? I can only find ABC - Keyboard. Also, typing alt (option?) + k results in ˚a.

Comment: @NobleUplift abc extended is just the new name for us extended which Apple decided to use a while ago.

Comment: @NobleUplift Typing option shift k in ABC Extended should produce Combining RIng Above.  You type it after the base character, e.g ẘ.  All this is described at http://sites.psu.edu/symbolcodes/mac/codemacext/

Comment: Returns `˚a` on my mac.

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica You are not using the abc extended keyboard I think.

Comment: @Tom Gewecke Yeah...

Answer (score 18):

This is just a option without changing the default Keyboard.

In **OS X**, this can be accomplished by **holding down** the <kbd>A</kbd> briefly and a pop-up will appear.

[image: Select diacritic]

Just select by clicking or typing the corresponding number.  In this case <kbd>8</kbd>

**ā ← Like that**

The repeat delay can be set to prevent eeeeeeeeee from happening too quickly.

[image: Keyboard settings]

Comment: If I hold down `a` it returns `aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa...` because I set `defaults write -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false`, but I don't like to get back. Thanks for your answer though.

Comment: I apologize.  I was thinking of others who may have had similar problems typing other diacritics that stumble across this question.  Your answer was the correct and accepted answer. It was perfect, I was merely elaborating.  I'll remove it.

Comment: Your answer is in fact the correct answer for most users.  It just so happens this poster has purposefully disabled the Character Picker, which is not normal.  His question ideally should have said that...

Comment: I agree.  That fact didn't come to light until mentioned in comments. :/

Comment: @TomGewecke I can agree. This kind of default settings is usually executed only once and thus I noticed I'm away from the default only after getting this answer and trying on my system. Sorry...

Comment: wow.  that's awesome!

Comment: His answer do not help the original question asker, but helped other people who searched for solution. Many thanks!