# Tilde shortcut duplicates my key

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut

When writing, I often need to use tildes like ó (but still need my keyboard to be in English), so I just hold the key down and press 4:

[image]

Usually it works fine. But several times have I ended up with this:

[image]

I don't know. It's like some sort of lag happens and the keystroke is repeated or something.

This is not software specific: it has happened to me in all sorts of applications with textfields. Even web browsers.

Is this a known problem? Is there a solution?

I am using Mac OSX Yosemite 10.10.3. I have a Macbook Pro 15" Retina Display Mid 2014. I don't use other Macs so I can't say I can reproduce this issue in them. I use the builtin keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

I didn’t know that holding a key in OS X produced a list like that. Very useful!

Not a direct answer to your question, but may help you, is that if you type <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> then <kbd>o</kbd> you will end up the the “ó” character.

The <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> combination gives you the acute diacritic mark, then you just enter the letter you want to put under it. So <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> then <kbd>e</kbd> works to get “é” too.

You can also do <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> then <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> to get “Ó”.

Comment: See also this related question: [Is it possible to type in macron (e.g. “ā”) without using U.S. Extended Keyboard?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/200063/120171)